TailwindCSS template literals strange behavior
I have the following component:
function SaleBadge({ textContent, badgeColor }) {
    return (
        <Badge className={`bg-${badgeColor}-200 hover:bg-${badgeColor}-300 animate-pulse align-middle ml-2`} variant="secondary"><Percent className="w-4 mr-2" />{textContent}</Badge>
    )
}

See how the background color of the Badge is determined using a template literal and the "badgeColor" prop? This is producing really strange results.
If I change the "-200" value to for example "-300", then no background color will be displayed as if I have entered a color value that does not exist. But... If I remove the "badgeColor" variable and replace it with a fixed color, like "violet-300" it will work as expected. And AFTER THAT, it will work using "badgeColor" prop. Any ideas?
I'm not sure whether this is expected or not, it seems as using template literals kind of works?
I tried making a function that returns the className string, but the issue persists for me:
function SaleBadge({ textContent, badgeColor }) {

    function returnBadgeClassName() {
        return(
            `bg-${badgeColor}-500 hover:bg-${badgeColor}-300 animate-pulse align-middle ml-2`
        )
    }

    return (
        <Badge className={returnBadgeClassName()} variant="secondary"><Percent className="w-4 mr-2" />{textContent}</Badge>
    )
}


As per the documentation:

The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files.
If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
Don’t construct class names dynamically
<div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>

In the example above, the strings text-red-600 and text-green-600 do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
Always use complete class names
<div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>


Thus, You can't make bg-${color}-500. instead you can do:
        <Badge className={`${badgeColor === "red" ? "bg-red-500" : badgeColor === "green" ? "bg-green-500" : "bg-blue-500"}animate-pulse align-middle ml-2`} variant="secondary"><Percent className="w-4 mr-2" />{textContent}</Badge>

Or it's better to pass the color as a prop to component and make this logic inside the component

See my updated response where I made a function that returns the classname string. The issue still persists though... When inspecting the element using the browser inspection, I can see that the correct bg-color is there, but its not rendering

The same mistake, please read the answer again. TailwindCSS operates with the concept of Just-In-Time (JIT) compilation. It extracts class names at the compiler level and outputs them in the CSS file. Tailwind doesn't recognize dynamic class names like text-${variable}-500, so they won't be included in the CSS file. It only understands static class names like text-red-500. If you have the class text-red-500 used elsewhere in the app, you can then use the variable.
